# Consuming web api with REST

Tags: c#, xaml

I am developing a Windows 8.1 application that consumes services from ASP.NET.

I want to display a club by id (application for managing clubs). In my welcome page I have a list of clubs (logos) when I click into a logo I want to display all information about the club concerned. (the get all works fine)

Here is my method

```
private Club GetClubById(int id) 
{ 
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    string result = httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://xxxxxx:2209/api/clubapi/" + id).Result;
    Club club = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Club>(result);
    return club; 
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    DefaultViewModel["ClubById"] = GetClubById(1003);
   //this ID already exists I don t know how to bind the id with the xaml.
}
```

My class:

```
          public class Club
          {
             public int IDClub { get; set; }
             public string ClubName { get; set; }

             public string ClubMail { get; set; }
             public string PhoneNumber { set; get; }
             public byte[] Logo { get; set; }
          }
```

This is my GridView in XAML:

```
<HubSection Width="500" Header="Clubs">

            <DataTemplate>
                <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding ListClubs}" SelectionMode="None" Tapped="GridView_Tapped"  >


                    <GridView.ItemTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
 <Image Source="{Binding Logo,Converter={StaticResource bytesToImageSourceConverter}}" Height="100" Width="200" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                                <TextBlock  TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="100"  >
          <Run Text="{Binding ClubName}" Foreground="Black"  > </Run>
                                </TextBlock>

                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                      </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                 </GridView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
```

Comment: Looks like you need to bind the club's ID to a hidden element in your data template and access the data in the OnNavigatedTo event.